# Algorithm for creating a list of items with maximum sum of scores

Tags: algorithms

I have a set of items $I\{a,b,c,...\}$.
I need to create an **ordered** list $L$ of a given size $m$.
Each combination of item $x$ and index $i$ gives a different score.
For example: if I put item $x$ at index $1$ it would give a score $s_{x,1}=S(x,1)$, which is not necessarily equal to $s_{x,2}=S(x,2)$ or any other score.
Also, each item can only be **used once** in the list.

How can I find the best combination of items to yield the maximum sum of scores for the composed list?

Preferably I need a fast algorithm (no brute force...)

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! Can you tell us what your own ideas are to solve this problem?

Comment: Hi! I am a computer programmer, but I don't have formal math qualifications. I started by trying to write an iterative function that gets the best scored item for each index, then goes back to see if any of the previously chosen items for the previous indices give a better result for the current index. But then I got stuck trying to re-organize the list. So I took a step back and tried to think of a few small example cases to get a better sense of the problem. Then I realized this could take a really long time to solve on my own... so here I am :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**

- Calculate [maximum weighted bipartite matching](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matching_%28graph_theory%29).
- If the list has to have exactly $m$ items, then use maximum *perfect* matching (it's enough to add the same big number to each weight).
- With positive weights and full bipartite graph maximum weighted matching will be perfect.

I hope this helps $\ddot\smile$

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I will have to read up on that topic to see if I can make it work. Once I do I'll be sure to accept your answer!

Comment: @Malki If you don't want to write it on your own and no library fits you, any linear programming solver will also work with only moderate increase in time complexity.